# can't starting Tomcat v8.0 at localhost

Tags: java, tomcat

I tried to create/run a java web app  and ran into the following error. I saw that other people have had similar problems, however, I tried what they said but they  all not work.

```
A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CourseServer]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CourseServer]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:132)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:783)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
... 20 more
```

and what's in my WEB-INF/lib 
[image]

Help!

Answer (score 2):

add below `dependency` into your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160212</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using `maven` then you have to download and add this `java-json.jar` to your build path

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException` means it can't find the class `JSONException` at runtime. Either you add it as a dependency in your `pom.xml`, add it to your build-path or you add the `JAR` to your `Tomcat Lib folder`.

Either way, you'll have to get the JAR containing the `JSONException`. Which can be found [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the means,they all not work until I reinstall tomacat....